# QTMultimedia setMedia member issue

Tags: c++, qt, include, qt-creator

I was trying to rebuild an old project, recreating a new project with all my old files, I get this weird error: "No member named 'setMedia' in 'QMediaPlayer' QMultimedia is well set up. The library has been changed? There are no resources on the web about this

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Qt6. In Qt6 `setMedia` was changed to `setSource`. You can find info in [docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qmediaplayer.html#setSource).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Qt 6.5 LTS and faced the same issue. Replacing setMedia by setSource worked for me.

void setSource(const QUrl &source); is coming from Qt 6 as per the documentation.

Please refer the documentation and check against your Qt version - https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaplayer.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).